# Ошибка aiogram(aiogram.utils.exceptions.BadRequest: Unsupported parse_mode)

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import markup as nav
from config import TOKEN
from aiogram import Bot


import pyautogui as pg
import pyscreenshot
import os
import subprocess

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

statuses = [ 'Epic Games', 'Steam', 'Dota 2', 'Chrome']



@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message):
    await message.reply("Ку", reply_markup=nav.markup)
    

@dp.message_handler()
async def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    elif message.text == 'Printscreen':
        image = pyscreenshot.grab()
        image.save('screenshot.png')
        await message.reply(message.chat.id, 'Скрин сделан!')
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id, types.InputFile('Pyton/TG bot/screenshot.png', 'rb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем тебе указывать 'rb'? Сделай так у меня работает

```
await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo=types.InputFile('Pyton/TG bot/screenshot.png'))
```